# The type 'IAsyncOperationWithProgress<,>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

In my `Xamarin.Forms` project i am trying to use `HttpClient` of `Windows.Web.Http`. 
I have to use that because i need to ignore some SSL errors.
When i create a `HttpClient` object and try to call a method i get this error message:

> Error CS0012  The type 'IAsyncOperationWithProgress<,>' is defined in
>   an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to
>   assembly 'Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract, Version=3.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'.

I ve done some research and tried everything i found but couldnt fix it.
How can i fix this ? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my Xamarin.Forms project i am trying to use HttpClient of Windows.Web.Http. I have to use that because i need to ignore some SSL errors. When i create a HttpClient object and try to call a method i get this error message.

You're using the `Windows.Web.Http` namespace is platform specific. The underlying implementation relies on the WindowsRT platform. Thus it is not cross-platform.

We recommend use `System.Net.Http` HttpClient module to make REST API calls in the Xamarin.Forms application. For more you could refer to [**Using HttpClient with Xamarin.Forms**](http://blog.xhackers.co/httpclient-with-xamarin-forms/).

- Install the package Microsoft.Net.Http from Nuget -> For making REST API calls
- Install the package Newtonsoft.Json from Nuget -> For Serialization/Deserialization of objects.

**Usage**

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var res = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:5000/api/todo/items");
```

Comment: Okay, i am well awared of that and i tried System.Net.Http too but in this case ignoring self-signed certificate errors is a problem.

Comment: Yep, you'd better create a new thread for ignoring self-signed certificate errors.

Comment: I have been searching for this for last 3 days but still couldnt find any proper solution. I would be appreciated if you can provide a solution.

Comment: Please see this thread of mine
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45481509/xamarin-forms-https-and-self-signed-certificate-issue/45481814#45481814. Thanks.

Comment: Yep. I am seeing !